# Taking log in sums

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory

While studying the zeta function and its convergence we consider $\zeta(s)$ and study it's behavior as $s\to 1^{+}$. This is useful in number theory for understanding the distribution of primes. However when we need to consider higher numbers $N\ge 5$ and the distribution modulo that we leave the realm of real number and consider the Dirichlet characters. Thus we construct the $L-$function of the character $L(\chi, s) = \sum_{n\ge1} \dfrac{\chi(s)}{n^s}$.

Now to use the Euler product we take $\log$ and consider the series $\log L(\chi, s) = \sum_{p}-\log(1-p^{-s})$. My question is, which branch of $\log$ do we take? Maybe after the computation it shall be clear that one straight line does not appear in the series, for example the negative reals never appears as a value; and as a result we are able to take the standard branch of $\log$. But *a priori* how we do we justify taking the $\log$?

Answer (score 0):

Use the principal branch $-\log(1-z) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k}$ analytic on $|z| < 1$ and $\log(1) = 0$.

What you really want is a Dirichlet series $$F(s) = -\sum_p \log(1-\chi(p) p^{-s}) = \sum_{p^k} \frac{\chi(p)^k}{k} p^{-sk}$$ analytic on $\Re(s) > 1$ such that $L(s,\chi) = e^{F(s)}$.

Then, if you can continue analytically $F(s)$ on $U$ then automatically $L(s,\chi) = e^{F(s)}$ stays true on $U$ and  $L(s,\chi)$  has no zeros there.

Also in general $\log(z)$ is analytic $\mathbb{C}^* \to \mathbb{C}/ 2i \pi \mathbb{Z}$, thus all you need is that $-\sum_p \log(1-\chi(p) p^{-s})$ converges modulo $2i \pi$, and this doesn't depend on the branches.

Finally $$F'(z) = \frac{L'}{L}(s,\chi) = \sum_{p^k} \chi(p)^k p^{-sk} \log p$$
is the quotient of two entire functions so it is meromorphic everywhere, which is how we get the [explicit formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explicit_formulae_(L-function)) from the residue theorem.